# How to add lines in TabPage of Tab Control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Tab Control in my sample Window form application. This contains two tab pages.

Is there any way to add lines as highlighted below ?

[image]

Comment: Put a `ListBox` inside that tab.

Comment: Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `ListBox` inside that tab.

Comment: It's funny, because when I read the question, I thought he meant the graphical (border) lines. I'm really sleepy =]

Answer (score 4):

Just put a `ListBox` inside of that `Tab`, and set its `Dock` property to `Fill`